# how to integrate android dialer keypad in my application

Tags: android, keypad

I want to integrate android in built key pad which has call and sms button at the bottom how can i do this in my application please suggest me the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `<EditText android:inputType="phone" />`

More information can be found here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html

If you just want to have a numeric only input field you can try this
 `<EditText android:numeric="decimal" />`

Comment: Thanks for replying.But using the <EditText android:inputType="phone" /> only numeric keypad appears we want dialer keypad which we can see in mobile phone while dialing a phone number for calling